# How to update a subtotal with ajax?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

On the checkout page, if you change the select, you need to change the subtotal and the total cost in review order table.

function.php

```
function bart_update_checkout_delivery(  ) {
  $price = $_POST['price'];
  $new_total = $price + 400;

  $cart = WC()->cart;
  $cart->total = $cart->total + $new_total;

  echo $cart->total;

  wp_die();
}
add_action('wp_ajax_bart_update_checkout_delivery', 'bart_update_checkout_delivery');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_bart_update_checkout_delivery', 'bart_update_checkout_delivery');
```

common.js

```
new SelectFx($('.cs-select--delivery')[0], {
  onChange: function(val) {
    currentDelivery = val;

    $.ajax({
        url: frontend.ajaxurl,
        data: {
        action: 'bart_update_checkout_delivery',
        price: 500
      },
        type: 'POST',
        success: function( price ) {
          $( document.body ).trigger( 'update_checkout' );
          $('.cart-delivery__value').html( price );             
        }
    });

  }
});
```

[Checkout Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uT0KA.png)

How to update total price in woocommerce cart? Now the value changes only on the frontend, but not at the order.

Comment: What does mean "if you change the select"? where? what select? can you clarify your question please. Your code is incomplete and not testable… remember that *"Questions seeking debugging help must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error **and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.**"*

Comment: Hi, i update my ask. I have select field, when i change it, I want to update subtotal in order review table using ajax.

Comment: Your actual code is incomplete and not testable.

Comment: Trigger **update_checkout** does not work. I unset basic fields in checkout page and add custom fields. I have dropdown list with delivery options. When i changed select field i will want update subtotal and total price.